# Doit-on dire "le faire taire" ou "le faire se taire"?

Tags: grammaire, verbes-pronominaux, constructions-causatives

Doit-on dire:

> Faites taire ce bruyant personnage!

Ou

> Faites se taire ce bruyant personnage!

A priori, la première forme me semble la plus utilisée, si pas la seule, mais pourquoi peut-on omettre le pronom dans ce cas? Après tout, "Alain tait" serait incorrect.

D'autre part, si l'omission est autorisée, est-elle pour autant obligatoire? Ou bien la deuxième forme est-elle correcte également? Autre exemple:

> L'infirmier fait asseoir le malade.
>
> L'infirmier fait s'asseoir le malade.

[La question a déjà été posée ailleurs](http://forum.wordreference.com/showthread.php?t=1805600) mais la réponse me laisse sur ma soif.

Comment: Je sais qu'on dit plutôt "me laisse sur ma faim", mais comme j'ai soif de savoir plutôt que faim, je me suis permis d'adapter.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

[L'un ou l'autre se dit ou se disent](http://fr.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dominique_Bouhours#cite_note-0). Je trouve « faire taire » plus naturel, et il semblerait qu'il soit effectivement nettement plus répandu (par exemple, le [corpus de l'université de Leipzig](http://wortschatz.uni-leipzig.de/ws_fra/) contient plus d'occurrences de « faire taire » que de « se taire »).

Le [Trésor de la langue française](http://www.cnrtl.fr/definition/taire) considère *faire taire* comme une locution obtenue par ellipse du pronom personnel (sens I.B.1). Je ne vois pas de différence de sens entre « faire se taire » et « faire taire ». Une [recherche Google](http://www.google.fr/?hl=fr&source=hp&q="faire+taire"+"faire+se+taire"#hl=fr&source=hp&q="faire+taire"+"faire+se+taire") de pages contenant les deux¹ retourne un certain nombre de résultats dans lesquels « faire se taire » est une coïncidence (par exemple « Que faire ? Se taire ou dénoncer ? »). Au hasard d'un [forum](http://www.etudes-litteraires.com/forum/topic30086-faire-forme-pronominale.html), je vois que le *Robert des Difficultés* signale

> Le verbe pronominal à l'infinitif perd presque toujours son pronom quand il est précédé de **faire** : *Je les ai fait taire*.

De même pour « faire asseoir » et « faire s'asseoir », je trouve le premier plus idiomatique et je ne vois pas de différence de sens. Je ne suis pas d'accord avec [la nuance que propose Dave](https://french.stackexchange.com/questions/354/doit-on-dire-le-faire-taire-ou-le-faire-se-taire/355#355) selon laquelle pour laquelle « faire s'asseoir » impliquerait un objet qui peut s'asseoir tout seul. Les premiers résultats d'une recherche sur Google de [`"faire asseoir"`](http://www.google.fr/?hl=fr&q="faire+asseoir"#hl=fr&q="faire+asseoir") et [`"faire s'asseoir"`](http://www.google.fr/?hl=fr&q="faire+s'asseoir"#hl=fr&q="faire+s'asseoir") ne me paraissent pas franchement différent, il y a par exemple un bébé et un animal dans les dix premiers résultats dans les deux cas. En cherchant [les deux](http://www.google.fr/?q="faire+asseoir"+"faire+s'asseoir"&hl=fr#q="faire+asseoir"+"faire+s'asseoir"&hl=fr), on tombe sur des textes qui passent indifféremment de l'un à autre.

Je reste moi aussi sur la soif à la lecture du [TLF](http://www.cnrtl.fr/definition/faire) (article **faire³** (verbe auxiliaire), partie I.D). (J'écris les abréviations en toutes lettres.)

> Remarque. L'omission du pronom réfléchi devant l'infinitif est courante. *Faire asseoir quelqu'un* ; *tu me fais marrer* (populaire). *Ferai-je pâmer les renchéris ?* (Ambrière, *Grandes vacances*, 1946, p. 158). Cependant le pronom est parfois maintenu lorsqu'il s'agit de verbes essentiellement pronominaux ou pour lever une ambiguïté. *Une rafale de mistral (...) faisait s'envoler les feuilles mortes* (Cendrars, Bourlinguer, 1948, p. 353).

J'ai au contraire l'impression que le pronom n'est omis que lorsqu'il s'agit de verbes essentiellement pronominaux, justement parce que ce n'est que dans ce cas qu'il n'y a pas d'ambiguïté. *Faire asseoir quelqu'un*, mais *faire se lever quelqu'un* (on ne dirait pas, en tout cas pas dans ce sens, <strike>faire level quelqu'un</strike>). Je me demande si, lorsqu'on omet le pronom réfléchi, le verbe à l'infinitif ne serait pas en fait employé transitivement (on fait que quelque chose assoie quelqu'un, on fait que quelque chose taise quelqu'un, etc., alors que la rafale de mistral ne fait pas que quelque chose envole les feuilles mortes). Cela pourrait à la rigueur fonctionner pour *pâmer* et *marrer*, qui pouvaient autrefois s'employer transitivement même si ce n'est plus le cas aujourd'hui.

¹ 
<sub>On pourrait aussi chercher « faire taire » et « faire se taire » séparément. Attention, le nombre de résultats est une approximation très grossière et non fiable — Google trouve « environ 272 000 résultats » pour `"faire se taire"`, 2 760 000 pour `"faire taire"` et 4 180 000 pour `"le faire taire"` !</sub>

Answer (score 6):

"Alain tait" (intransitif) est incorrect, mais "taire" comme verbe transitif direct [existe](http://www.larousse.fr/encyclopedie/nom-commun-autre/taire/95636):

> "taire quelque chose" = ne pas dire

Même chose pour asseoir, où le sens transitif direct moderne serait un peu plus abstrait (asseoir une personne, une idée) que son emploi transitif indirect.

À partir de là, je dirais que les deux formes sont correctes, et leur nuance respective (très légère, pour "[se] taire") dépend de la nuance de la forme transitive directe/indirecte:

> Faire taire: empêcher une chose d'être dite (si nécessaire, en éliminant ou bloquant physiquement la personne qui pourrait la dire).
>
> Faire **se** taire: convaincre une personne de ne pas faire usage de la parole (à la pointe d'un couteau si nécessaire)

C'est plus clair pour "[s']asseoir":

> Faire asseoir: n'importe quelle action qui résulte en la position assise de l'objet (y compris si celui-ci n'est pas forcément capable de s'asseoir tout seul: bébé etc.)
>
> Faire **s'** asseoir: inviter/guider/forcer une personne à s'asseoir (implique que la personne *pourrait* s'asseoir seule).

Comment: Plus j'y pense et moins je suis d'accord avec une nuance de sens. Je n'ai pas l'impression d'en faire, et mon approche absolument non systématique de recherche Google n'en montre pas non plus. Est-ce que la nuance correspond à un usage conscient chez toi, est-ce que tu l'as rencontrée chesz d'autres ?

Comment: Je n'ai personnellement aucun argument, mais je suis d'accord avec Dave sur ce point. Le « se »/« s' » inspire chez moi que l'action a été « posée » par la personne en question. Je met « posée » entre guillemets car dans le cas de « s'endormir », je considère que si une personne se couche, elle a posé le geste, mais on utilise un sédatif, on la endormir, pas s'endormir.

Answer (score 6):

Je suis globalement d'accord avec la réponse de Dave sur les différences de sens entre *faire X qqn* et *faire se X qqn*. Je pense que dans le cas de *faire taire*, l'usage est un peu différent du cas général. Je n'employerais pas *faire se taire*.

---

Le verbe *taire* est employé comme réflexif (i.e. *se taire*) lorsqu'il s'agit d'une personne. Cependant, dans la forme *se taire* (attestée par le TLF dès le XIII<sup>e</sup> siècle), le pronom personnel est omis.

---

Le *Littré* dit:

> **taire**
>   11. Faire taire (avec ellipse du pronom personnel), imposer silence, réduire au silence. *Faites taire ce bavard.*

Le *Trésor de la Langue Française* concorde :

> [Avec ellipse du pronom personnel] **Faire taire qqn**
>   a) Interrompre quelqu'un; imposer silence à une personne qui pleure ou qui crie. *Faire taire brutalement; faire taire d'une gifle.*
>   b) Empêcher quelqu'un de s'exprimer, le réduire au silence. Synon. *museler*. *Faire taire des adversaires, ses détracteurs, ses ennemis.*

Comment: Donc c'est juste pour "se taire"? Et juste dans l'expression "faire taire"? Quid de "s'asseoir"?